# Armstrong numbers. Fails for 153

Tags: c++, loops, number-theory

A C++ program to compute and display all Armstrong numbers (numbers such that the sum of each of the digits raised to the power of the number of digits equals the number) between 100 and 999. The answers should be 153, 370, 371, 407. It prints all but 153.

Debugging done to see what the values of the individual digits are for i = 153.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>

void separateDigits(int n, std::vector<int>& digits)
{
    if (n>0)
    {
        separateDigits(n/10, digits);
        digits.push_back(n%10);
    }
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 100; i <= 999; i++)
    {
        std::vector<int> test;
        separateDigits(i, test);

        int powerSum = 0;
        for (auto iter = test.begin(); iter != test.end(); iter++)
        {
            //powerSum = powerSum + pow((*iter),3);
            powerSum = powerSum + (*iter)*(*iter)*(*iter);
        }

        if (i==powerSum)
        {
            std::cout << "Armstrong: " << i << std::endl;
        }

    }


    return 0;
}
```

[image: Output screenshot]

Comment: I see 153 [*printed*](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JF3AH2lLSLqxVa5I)

Comment: `pow` is a floating-point function, and as such it will have rounding errors. Why not use plain integer multiplication instead, as in `*iter * *iter * *iter`?

Comment: Your code works totally fine for me!

Comment: Strange. Doesn't work for me, screenshot added to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h> //PROGRAM TO FIND ARMSRONG NUMBERS.
#include <math.h>  //WORKS ONLY FOR THREE DIGIT NUMBERS.

int main()
{
int num, dig1, dig2, dig3;
for (num = 1; num <= 999; num++)
{

    dig3 = dig2 = dig1 = 0;
    dig3 = num % 10;
    dig2 = ((num - dig3) % 100) / 10;
    dig1 = (num - (dig3 + 10 * dig2)) / 100;
    if (num == pow(dig1, 3) + pow(dig2, 3) + pow(dig3, 3))
    {
        printf("%d\n", num);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `pow` for `int`s.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem like your best option:

```
powerSum = powerSum + (*iter)*(*iter)*(*iter);
```

as you've now embedded your previous constant `3`:

```
powerSum = powerSum + pow((*iter),3);
```

in an evem more obscure fashion.  Why not consider a cleaner way that also supports numbers of sizes other than three digits:

```
    unsigned digitsSize = test.size();

    for (auto iter = test.begin(); iter != test.end(); iter++)
    {
        unsigned power = 1;

        for (unsigned size = 0; size < digitsSize; size++) {
            power *= *iter;
        }

        powerSum += power;
    }
```

The complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void separateDigits(unsigned number, std::vector<unsigned>& digits)
{
    while (number > 0)
    {
        digits.push_back(number % 10);
        number /= 10;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<unsigned> digits;

    for (unsigned number = 100; number <= 999; number++)
    {
        separateDigits(number, digits);

        unsigned powerSum = 0, digitsSize = digits.size();

        for (std::vector<unsigned>::iterator iter = digits.begin(); iter != digits.end(); iter++)
        {
            unsigned power = 1;

            for (unsigned size = 0; size < digitsSize; size++) {
                power *= *iter;
            }

            powerSum += power;
        }

        if (number == powerSum)
        {
            std::cout << "Armstrong: " << number << std::endl;
        }

        digits.clear();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Changing the range from 100 - 999 to 1000 - 9999, no longer breaks the code, but instead produces:

```
> ./a.out
Armstrong: 1634
Armstrong: 8208
Armstrong: 9474
>
```